How to click on the selected row again to unselect it in Avalonia DataGrid?
The default behaviour of a DataGrid is to select when a row is clicked , however I also wish for the row to un-select if it was previously already selected when clicked.
I find the code for WPF,but don't work in Avalonia.
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                         Handler="DoCheckRow"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <!-- Column mapping omitted. -->
</DataGrid>

public void DoCheckRow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing) {
        DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
        if (row != null) {
            row.IsSelected = !row.IsSelected;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

